# Custom title strings in Sphinx 'contents' section

Tags: python-sphinx, substitution, restructuredtext, sections

I have reStructuredText file for Sphinx documentation similar to this:

```
Page Title
==========

**Contents**

.. contents::
   :local:
   :backlinks: none

----

Subtitle |mongodb_icon| |postgre_icon|
--------------------------------------

Some totally irrelevant text here...
```

(`|mongodb_icon|` and `|postgre_icon|` substitutions are defined in `rst_prolog` in `conf.py`)

Is it possible to render out the `Subtitle` in Contents without `|mongodb_icon| |postgre_icon|` part somehow? I'd like to have different strings for 'contents' section and for the title itself, especially because in this way, generated URLs also include that text which I would like to avoid (e.g. _build/html/docs/page.html#subtitle-mongodb-icon-postgres-icon).